# Strange issue with python requests.get method

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, configuration-files, http-error

Oh Brother!, I have been scratching my head over this for past two hours. Finally I decided to turn this over to mighty powers at stackoverflow. ye o python warriors, please help

This works :

```
requests.get('https://abc.123.xyz.xom/getmethisurl',
             auth=('PasswordIsAuthToken', 'khcdhk-dcbdmsb-dcbdsm-aBSDCXKN'),
             verify=False)
```

This doesn't, getting a 401 every time :

#### defconn.py

```
import json
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth


class connect(object):

    def __init__(self, url, user, token):
        self.url=url
        self.user=user
        self.token=token

    def uget(self, uri):
        self.url = self.url + uri

        ## EDIT 1 : Code added to print out the parameters values and type for debugging
        print ("IN:", repr(self.url), repr(self.user), repr(self.token))
        print(self.url, type(self.url))
        print(self.user, type(self.user))
        print(self.token, type(self.token))

        res=requests.get(self.url, auth=(self.user, self.token), verify=False)
        if res.status_code == 401:
           print ("ERORR 401 !!!!")
        else:
           return res
```

#### app.py (This is the main script)

```
import defconn
from connexion.resolver import RestyResolver

props = dict(line.strip().split('=') for line in open('env.properties'))

url=props['connect.url']
user=props['connect.username']
token=props['connect.token']

oj=defconn.connect(url,user,token)
oj.uget('/getmethisurl')
```

Here is my env.properties :

#### env.properties

```
connect.url=https://abc.123.xyz.xom
connect.username=PasswordIsAuthToken
connect.token=khcdhk-dcbdmsb-dcbdsm-aBSDCXKN
```

#### Output

[image: output]

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Edit 1 : Adding the diagnostic code as well as its output screenshot too

Thanks - A

Comment: Show us the whole program (at the very least, you're missing `import requests`.)  Perhaps there's some other detail you omitted that will prove enlightening.

Comment: Also, I notice that in your "working" example, you don't capture the _results_ of the get call.  (Yes, I'm splitting hairs, but you never know what small detail is relevant in questions like these.)

Comment: One component of this that I find odd is that you are modifying `self.url` when I think you may just intend to create a new variable and concatenate `self.url` with `uri`. If you call `oj.uget` more than once, `self.url` is different than the value with which it was initialized because it has been modified by the earlier calls

Comment: @JohnGordon Added the complete program. Thanks for looking into this

Comment: @danielcorin,Thanks, Good Point, Will make that correction

Comment: Found it. It was an incorrect parameter coming from the properties file. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The likely cause is that somewhere along the way the parameters don't match the simple hard-code example.  Try adding a diagnostic line so that you can isolate the problem:

```
class connect(object):

    def __init__(self, url, user, token):
        self.url=url
        self.user=user
        self.token=token

    def uget(self, uri):
        self.url = self.url + uri
        print(repr(self.url), repr(self.user), repr(self.token)) # <== DIAGNOSTIC
        res=requests.get(self.url, auth=(self.user, self.token), verify=False)
        if res.status_code == 401:
           print ("ERORR 401 !!!!")
        else:
           return res
```

As noted in the comments, the `self.url = self.url + uri` probably isn't what you want.  Instead, just update a local variable.

Comment: Thanks Ray. That was the first thing I tried though, the type and values of the parameters both match with hard coded example.

Comment: Have updated the original question with diagnostic lines and the output.

Comment: Found it. It was an incorrect parameter coming from the properties file. Thanks for the help.